# Fetch more data in RxJs

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have some problem with apply fetching "more" data using `fromFetch` from rxjs.
I have project with React and RXJS. Currently I'm using something like this:

```
  const stream$ = fromFetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100', {
    selector: response => response.json()
  }).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

But! I would like to change limit dynamically, when I click button or even better - when I scroll to the very bottom of my website. How to make something like this?
So that, based on some interaction, the limit would change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your observable work in your case it's a request-response. You're declaring stream$ to be an observable that when someone subscribes it will make a request with limit=100.

There are different ways of solving this... The most straightforward would be:

```
const getPokemon$ = limit =>
  fromFetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=' + limit, {
    selector: response => response.json()
  });

const MyComponent = () => {
  // ...
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const sub = getPokemon$(limit).subscribe(res => console.log(res));

    return () => sub.unsubscribe();
  }, [limit])

  // ...
}
```

Another option, probably a bit more reactive but harder to follow for others, would be to declare another stream which sets the limit:

```
const limit$ = new BehaviorSubject(100)

const pokemon$ = limit$.pipe(
  switchMap(limit => fromFetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=' + limit, {
    selector: response => response.json()
  }))
);

// In your component

const MyComponent = () => {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    const sub = pokemon$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));

    return () => sub.unsubscribe();
  }, [])

  changeLimit = (newLimit) => limit$.next(newLimit)

  // ...
}
```

In this other solution, you're declaring how pokemon$ should react to changes on limit$, and you can set limit$ from any other component you want.

Comment: Great! Thank You, but one more question. Can I use BehaviorSubject as a state? For store my data(pokemons)?
And why did You use switchMap ?

Comment: on BehaviourSubject - Yes, but be careful not to abuse it.... if you have dozens of behavioursubjects with interdependencies it might be hard to maintain it. I guess for one or two it won't hurt.

Comment: switchMap cancels the previous request if a new one comes in, I thought it would make more sense in this case. Other posibilities are mergeMap (it doesn't cancel previous requests, and maybe you receive the response in a different order), concatMap (it waits until the previous ends) or exhaustMap (it ignores new requests until the last one completes). switchMap sounds better in this use case (i guess :o)